# How to remove 1px extra border on DIVs in IE7?

Tags: html, css

I am having divs each includes one Text field. 
I have textfield with height:25px and div with margin-top:5px;
In all browsers other than IE7,the page renders with div having same height as textfield and proper margin. 
But in IE7 , it gives extra space vertically to the divs hence my page looks stretched.

I have tried various solutions like display:none, clear:both, padding:0, margin:0.
I have compared box model in all browsers also, in IE7 only it shows additional height on div element.

Is there any CSS trick to handle this IE7 problem? 
Thank You.

```
Sample code :- 
HTML : 
<div>
<input class="myInput"  type="text" />
</div>
<div>
<input class="myInput"  type="text" />
</div>

CSS:

.myInput{
    border: 1px solid #336699; color: #666666; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; height: 13px; font: arial; padding: 5px;
}

.ie7 div{ padding:0 margin:0;}
```

this will make my textfield to height of 25px in total. The enclosing div do not have any styles.
I have tried css hacks in IE7 with

Comment: textfield is 13 px accrdng to the css and you say its 25!

Comment: textfield height 13px + padding-top 5px + padding-bottom 5px + top-border 1px + bottom-border 1px = 25px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess is because in modern browsers some `<input>` types has the property `box-sizing:border-box` or you have set that property somewhere; that makes the `height` is not increasing with the border value but in IE7 that property is not supported.

You can make an specific value hack fo IE7 and lower on your height discounting the border size:

```
.yourinput {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height:25px;
  *height:23px; /*real height - border size*/
}
```

Comment: If I reduce height then form looks ugly.

Comment: Reduce real height is what box-sizing:border-box does ... with this you are just making the work of border-bx for IE7 @HemantBarhate

Comment: Thanks @Danko, i know box model in IE and other browsers is different and your suggestion did helped me but I used conditional style sheets rather than hacks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use IE7 hack like below,

```
*+html .YourClassName { /*CSS rule*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

IE7 and other's will set their own border on input divs. So set a border to 0px if you don't want a border.

You can do so like:

```
input {
   border: 0px solid silver;
}
```

or even more specific

```
input[type="text"] {
   border: 0px solid silver;
}
```

Comment: inputs does not have any problem. i tried only inputs in my page it renders correctly in IE7 without any extra spacing

Answer (score 0):

This may be another option for you. You may use conditional css where you can write seprate styles for IE7. 
You may visit the following link where you will be able to see the usage of conditional css.

http://www.conditional-css.com/usage.